# How does the Gelfond–Schneider theorem prove $e^\pi$ is transcendental?

Tags: proof-verification, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

The Gelfond–Schneider theorem only gives criteria for $a^b$ being transcendental so long as both $a$ and $b$ are algebraic, but further, that $b$ is irrational.

I could understand arranging it to the form of $(e^{i\pi})^{-i}$, since $e^{i \pi}$  and $-i$ are both algebraic, but then how the hell is $i$ irrational? It's only one integer unit away from the complex origin.

Comment: $i$ is a _Gaussian integer_, but it is not _rational_. That is, it is not the quotient of two elements of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Quoting [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond–Schneider_theorem): "The values of a and b are not restricted to real numbers; complex numbers are allowed (they are never rational when they have an imaginary part not equal to 0, even if both the real and imaginary parts are rational)."

Comment: The link above states the theorem as $b$ being non-rational, not irrational.

Comment: Hi TeXnichal: your number is the well known Gelfond's constant and you can certainly see the proof in internet.

Comment: Wiki states that b is irrational

Comment: @TeXnichal I also saw that the Wiki used the word irrational. I believe they are using the word to mean non-rational. Technically, non-real numbers are not irrational as you point out. In this theorem, I believe irrational has the meaning "not rational".

Comment: But an irrational number is either transcendental or it's not, so if it was in general just "not rational" that would include transcendental numbers, which it can't by the theorem.